# Unable to install R 3.6.0 on centos

Tags: r, centos7, yum

When I was trying install R on centos 7 using the below command, older version is getting installed instead of latest version(3.6.0).

Command :

`yum install R -y`

Required suggestions on how to install latest version(3.6.0) of R on Centos 7.

Comment: As far as I can tell, version 3.6.0 is not yet available in the CentOS repositories. It is, however, not very difficult to install R from source. A very easy and accessible guide published by RStudio is available [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218004217-Building-R-from-source), and you can get the source code for R 3.6.0 [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/) (at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 1):

```
yum --enablerepo=epel-testing install R
```

source:
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-testing-x86_64/R-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html